# Системы счисления

Tags: системы-счисления

Число X = (64^32 + 16^8 -1) * 8^4 + 4^2 -1 перевели из десятичной в двоичную систему счисления. Сколько единиц получилось в двоичной записи числа? В ответе укажите целое число.

Comment: Давайте зачётку...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
10000111010101110101
```

Выходит, 11.

Для: (64^32 + 16^8 - 1) * 8^4 + 4^2 - 1

> забыл степень поставить =) извеняюсь

Тогда осмелюсь предположить, что ответ - 13.

64^32 даст число с одной единицей, 16^8 - аналогично. Если их сложить, то будет число с двумя единицами (одна останется в начале, одна появится где-то в середине, как например если 65536 сложить с 256). Вычесть из этого 1, будет число с 9 единицами. (напр. те же 65536 - 255). Умножим это число на 8^4 получим просто нули на хвост (в количестве 12 штук). И теперь прибавляем 15 - получим ещё 4 единицы. Итого 9 + 4 = 13.

Comment: забыл степень поставить =) извеняюсь

Comment: Задача сразу стала тяжело проверяемой на калькуляторе)

Comment: понравился ход решения, спасибо!

Comment: Перечитываю сейчас ответ, нагнал я пожалуй про 9 единиц после вычитания 1 из большого числа, содержащего две единицы. Интересно узнать правильный ответ...

Answer (score 2):

[@Kremchik](/users/2389/kremchik), у меня 16 получилось (может напутал где ?) Смотрите

```
64^32 (38 zeros)
100000000000000000000000000000000000000

16^8  (12 zeros)
                          1000000000000
(64^32+16^8-1)
100000000000000000000000000111111111111
(64^32+16^8-1)*8^4
100000000000000000000000000111111111111000000000000
(64^32+16^8-1)*8^4+16
100000000000000000000000000111111111111000000010000
(64^32+16^8-1)*8^4+16-1
100000000000000000000000000111111111111000000001111
```

Считаем единички (у меня 16). Делал в Emacs.

Comment: Мм, 16^8 = 4294967296, что даёт, кажется, 32 нуля. Значит (64^32+16^8-1) в итоге должно дать 1 (в начале) + 32 единицы. А потом да, прибавляем нули в конец, а затем добавляя 15, добавляем 4 единицы в конец. Может тогда 37 ответ конечный?

Comment: Да, ошибся, степени ведь умножать надо, а не складывать. 32+5 = 37. **Точно**.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=... //неважно чему
char[] chars=Integer.toBinaryString(x).toCharArray();
int count=0;
for(char ch:chars)
   if(ch=='1')
       count++;
System.out.println("В двоичном представлении числа '"+x+"' содержится "+count+" единичек");
```

Это Java

Comment: []()  

    .toString().replace("0", "").length

Comment: Молодец, оч. хитро!

Comment: Так красивее :)

Answer (score 0):

X = (64<sup>32</sup> + 16<sup>8</sup> - 1) * 8<sup>4</sup> + 4<sup>2</sup> - 1 = (2<sup>6*32</sup> + 2<sup>32</sup>-1) * 2<sup>12</sup> + 2<sup>4</sup> - 1.
Единички разнесены, поэтому их можно сложить: 1 + 32 + 4 = 37